# error: field 'list_member' has incomplete type

Tags: c, struct, field

I am currently trying to compile the Intel MPSS for the Xeon Phi from source, since the packages are not available on other disributions than RHEL and SUSE.

I already fixed some compile errors like defines or type errors.

But still I get the following error

```
error: field 'list_member' has incomplete type
```

Here's the code where it 'happens'

```
struct scif_callback 
{
    struct list_head        list_member;
    scif_callback_t         callback_handler;
};
```

And I do not know how to fix this one.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: The error tells you that `struct list_head` is unknown to the compiler when reaching `list_member`'s declaration.

Comment: Where is the `struct list_head` defined?

Comment: The compiler cannot see the definition of struct list_head. It needs to know its size to know how big to make struct scif_callback. Do you need an extra #include or should list_member be a pointer?